# Use data from img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image tag that looks like:

```
<img data-original="imgserv/profilepics/2/702296.jpg" src="imgserv/blank.JPG" 
 id="702296" user_ip="65.346.36.192" class="lazy">
```

In jQuery, if I do

```
$('.lazy').on('click', function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

I'll get the specific `id` I need.

How can I make it so that I can also retrieve the data inside `user_ip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select that attribute like this (inside a click handler):

```
var user_ip = $(this).attr('user_ip');
```

I suggest you make it a data attribute like `data-original`:

```
<img ... data-user-ip="...">
```

Then:

```
var user_ip = $(this).data('user-ip');
```